# Facebook Graph API: Get page token with javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, token

I'm building a website for a client. I am pulling through his Facebook Posts & his ratings onto his website using Javascript. I have a Page Token (getting 'ratings' data required the page token rather than the standard access token) in place and everything runs as expected, until the token expires.

Obviously I cant be logging in every hour to update the token just to keep this working, so what is the correct way to call this with JavaScript when a user opens my clients webpage.

Comment: So the Page Access Token is exposed in the JS? That'd be not really adviseable...

Comment: Thanks Tobi. This is all currently running locally so i'll make sure I address that before it goes live.

Comment: The catch is: If you're just using the JS SDK, the Access Token will be exposed no matter if you run this in development or production, at least if you store it somewhere in your code.

Comment: Ye, I think I might have a go at a PHP solution instead. As a front-end developer, I'm way more familiar with JS than PHP, so I naturally took that approach first thinking it was somehow achievable. Thanks again.